# Maven build with SASS does not work in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sass

I have a project, which builds fine locally.  When I run mvm clean deploy it builds fine and the sass-maven plugin gives me the following output:

```
[INFO] --- sass-maven-plugin:1.1.1:update-stylesheets (default) @ myapp-web ---
[INFO] Compiling SASS Templates
[INFO] Queing SASS Template for compile: /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7669.abTest.boldKeywords.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7669.abTest.boldKeywords.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7728.abTest.common.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7728.abTest.common.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7728.abTest.noDescription.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/features/abTestStyles/css/S7728.abTest.noDescription.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/pages/coolSearchResults/css/coolSearchResults.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/pages/coolSearchResults/css/coolSearchResults.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/pages/hotSearchResults/css/hotSearchResults.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/pages/hotSearchResults/css/hotSearchResults.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/homeStatic.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/homeStatic.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/merchant.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/merchant.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/offer.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/offer.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/bizratmyappe-eu-webapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/product.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/product.css
[INFO]     >> /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/searchResults.scss => /Users/750250/Projects/myapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/catalogue/theme/bi_fr/css/pages/searchResu
```

Indicating that it works.  However, when the same thing is run from Jenkins, I get the following output from the plugin

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - --- sass-maven-plugin:1.1.1:update-stylesheets (default) @ myapp-web ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- sass-maven-plugin:1.1.1:update-stylesheets (default) @ myapp-web ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.jasig.maven.plugin.sass.UpdateStylesheetsMojo - Compiling SASS Templates
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.jasig.maven.plugin.sass.UpdateStylesheetsMojo - Queing SASS Template for compile: /home/sitebuild/jenkins/workspace/{myapp}-myapp-webapp-{S7515}/webapp/src/main/webapp => /home/sitebuild/jenkins/workspace/{myapp}-myapp-webapp-{S7515}/webapp/src/main/webapp
```

It appears that it is just ignoring or not picking up the contents of that directory.

What would cause this behaviour when running the sass-maven-plugin within jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replicated your issue and it appears to be a bug in the SASS plugin - the good news is there is a workaround.

The absolute path your Jenkins server is passing to the plugin contains curly braces. This is a common source of bugs in Ruby programs, which the Maven SASS plugin is. Doing this locally replicated your problem exactly - the plugin starts, then simply does not compile anything.

When I built a POM that used relative paths instead of absolute paths (`src/main/sass` vs `${project.dir}/src/main/sass`)), it was possible to build in a directory whose path contained curly braces.

It would be good if the plugin reported that the path it is trying to compile from seems problematic though.